# Add Shortcode to All Post Types

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I want to display shortcodes (I'm using fruitful Shortcode) above the post title tag (H1). And I want to display it to all my post (also as a template).

[i want to be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzq46.png)

Thanks.

Comment: You want to add this shortcode to show on every post and post type on your website?
You can edit templates? you may call this shortcode via php there like do_shortcode() ,

or if you want to do it from one place you might do it via the_title filter and prefix title with the output of that shortcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to adjust the way your single posts are displayed for all the posts, you have to edit the single.php file in your theme folder. You can do this in the backend under "Design" -> "Theme Editor" or you can access the folder and files via FTP.

For your default posts in wordpress you just need to open the single.php file and look for the h1 with your title. It can look something like:

```
<h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
```

Above that (if you want to display it above), you can put your shortcode with the do_shortcode() function:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[name_of_shortcode]'); ?>
```

---

If you are not using normal posts of wordpress but custom post types or something else, please have a look at the wordpress template hierarchy to find out, which file to edit or how to name the new files for creating template files: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

---

If you are using a theme that is not made by you, you should make sure you keep your theme updateable. So if you overwrite the single.php, with the next update of your theme, the file will not have your edits. You need a child theme, if you want to keep your parent theme up to date but also customize it in the page templates. Here is a nice tutorial for child themes: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/01/create-customize-wordpress-child-theme/

Comment: You are the man! Thanks a bunch for your detailed help @rank. Have a great weekend :)